# Error on Save: Specified Cast is not Valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I get this error :

> Value cannot be null

I have a viewmodel that references multiple models.
In view, html helpers are strongly-typed.
In post action in controller, it receives viewmodel.
I have multiple cases in `POST`,
one case is to save some fields of (one) table referenced in viewmodel,
other cases to save some fields to (multiple) tables referenced in viewmodel

I added a breakpoint and traced the code, `ModelState` doesn't return any null values, but when the debugger reaches  `var sod_request = new SOD_REQUEST` , it doesn't get into the code block and throws the `'Value cannot be null'` error, pointing to property of another model that I don't want to post data to in the first case.

I handled validation in viewmodel, using foolproof library.
The properties that I get 'Value cannot be null' on, has `RequiredIfFalse` validation attribute

I post all `not null` columns of `SOD_REQUEST`

In the Get method of the same action, I map all attributes of all models

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Initiate(SViewModel vm)
{
        if (vm.IsDelegated == true) //if user checks Delegate
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                    {
                        REQUEST_ID = TempData["SRequestID"].ToString(),
                        CREATION_DATE = DateTime.Now.Date,
                        INITIATOR_ID = (Int32)TempData["InitiatorID"],
                        SERVICE_TYPE_ID = 1
                    };

                    db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return View("Success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes.");
                Console.Write("check error:    " + ex);
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
```

}

I'm expecting to save to one table only the attributes I mapped

Why it asks for a field in another model to have a value?
Is it because I'm using strongly-typed views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the line new SOD_REQUEST that is executing all of the following:

```
                WS_REQUEST_ID = TempData["SODRequestID"].ToString(),
                CREATION_DATE = DateTime.Now.Date,
                INITIATOR_ID = (Int32)TempData["InitiatorID"],
                INITIATOR_NAME = TempData["InitiatorName"].ToString(), //may remove later
                SERVICE_TYPE_ID = 1,
                INITIATOR_COMMENTS = vm.InitiatorComments,
                DELEGATED_EMPLOYEE_ID = vm.DelegatedTeamMemberId,
                IS_DELEGATED = vm.IsDelegated,
                REQUEST_STATUS = (Int32)CommonClasses.RequestStatus.DELEGATED
```

I'm guessing TempData["SODRequestID"] or TempData["InitiatorName"] is null. If so, easy fix:

```
            WS_REQUEST_ID = TempData["SODRequestID"]?.ToString(),
            INITIATOR_NAME = TempData["InitiatorName"]?.ToString(), //may remove later
```

Note the ? I added.

Comment: I added the ?. Is it supposed to accept null values now? I tried it anyway, and still pointing to the property of another model in the form as null. I'm now tracing values inside SOS_REQUEST block

Comment: I added the ?. Is it supposed to accept null values now? because i don't want to post null values, these are not null in db. I traced the values of properties i'm posting, all hold values

Comment: I assigned each TempData value to a local variable, and one returned null like you pointed out. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, the ? means if everything up to that point is null, apply null to the variable and stop processing. BTW, can you accept this answer? That will put me over 10,000 points.

Comment: so it won't post if it's null? or it'll accept null? I accepted your answer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
  var s_request = new S_REQUEST(
                    {
                        REQUEST_ID = TempData["SRequestID"].ToString(),
                        CREATION_DATE = DateTime.Now.Date,
                        INITIATOR_ID = (Int32)TempData["InitiatorID"],
                        SERVICE_TYPE_ID = 1
                    });
```

Use this because () brackets are required with constructor

Answer (score 0):

you should check is null before parse data

```
REQUEST_ID = (TempData["SRequestID"] != null)? TempData["SRequestID"].ToString() : TempData["SRequestID"], 

INITIATOR_ID = (TempData["InitiatorID"] != null)? Int32.Parse(TempData["InitiatorID"]):TempData["InitiatorID"],
```